# Continuous subgroup of SO(3)?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups

I read from a paper[arXiv: cond-mat/0602109](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/cond-mat/0602109) by a theoretical physicist, Prof. Frank Bais,  close subgroups of $SO(3)$ is given by ${C_n,D_n,T,O,I,SO(2)\rtimes Z_2}$, where $C_n$ is the  cyclic group of order $n$, $D_n$ is dihedral group of order $n$, $T$ is the tetrahedral group, $O$ is the octahedral group, and $I$ is the icosahedral group. However, I have some questions to understand this.

1. Is $SO(2)$ a subgroup of $SO(3)$? The subgroups listed in the paper mentioned above is about close subgroups. What's the meaning of 'close' here?
2. If $SO(2)$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$, can it be parameterized as a $3\times 3$ matrix as \begin{align}
   \left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
   \end{array}
   \right)
   \end{align}
   with a imagined '$z$' axis?
3. Can the subgroup $SO(2)\rtimes Z_2$ be parameterized as a $3\times 3$ matrix? E.g,
   \begin{align}
   \left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \ 1
   \end{array}
   \right),
   \left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    \cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 \\
    \sin\theta & -\cos\theta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \ -1
   \end{array}
   \right)
   \end{align}

Moreover, any suggestions of tutorial references or textbooks that I can find the list of subgroups or the way I can calculate them by myself are also warmly welcome. I am not familiar with continuous groups.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.  Closed means closed as a subset in the topology of SO(3).

Comment: Thanks, Mariano. Do you know some reference s or textbook that I can find the list of the subgroup of SO(3) or the way I can calculate them by myself? I am not familiar with continuous groups. @mariano